# JFreeChart bar chart too crowded on the X-axis

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am trying to produce a distribution of some "score" function. This function is scoring in the [1..100] range so I have data points in the following form:

```
 score 1: n1 counts
 score 2: n2 counts
 ...
 score 100: n100 counts
```

I tried to use a *Bar Chart* (using `ChartFactory.createBarChart(...)`) but the result is too crowded on the x-axis where I have 100 categories (for scores 1 to 100):

[image]

Note that the results shown above have a huge concentration (spike) around score 78 but that's not the problem. Even if they were nicely distributed I would still get an overloaded x axis.

Is there an easy remedy or should I be looking into some other kind of chart?

Comment: Just display the x-axis labels in increments of 10?

Comment: @JoshM this is a `CategoryPlot`, the x-axis is returned with `getDomainAxis()` which returns a `CategoryAxis`, not a `NumberAxis`. I am not sure if what you are suggesting is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I got better results with an `IntervalXYDataset` and using `ChartFactory.createXYBarChart`:

[image]

Comment: This is the right approach...in JFreeChart we distinguish between categorical x-values (CategoryPlot) and numerical x-values (XYPlot).